# Retrieving Username from Process ID using Windows Command

Tags: windows, command

I am trying to get the list of users running a process say test.exe. I am using the following code:-

```
tasklist /fo table /nh /fi "Imagename eq test.exe"
```

But, it doesn't give me the Usernames for the process but only PID's.

Can I use tasklist to get the username? Or will I need additional commands to do that?

Please help.

Comment: just add `/v` to your command

Comment: The next question comes, I can run tasklist to retrieve user names only when I run tasklist command as Administrator. I gave the full rights to Everyone and tried it, still the effect is same. It shows the user names as UNKNOWN. Any clues? I don't want to put it in Task Scheduler and run the task as Administrator. I just want to do it directly.